# What is the Withdrawal Pattern?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, security, design-patterns

I am reading this article : https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/why-use-the-withdrawal-pattern-d5255921ca2a

It seems interesting. Could anyone explain the idea of the Withdrawal pattern in a simple way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The withdrawal pattern places the responsibility for claiming funds, on the recipient of the funds: the recipient has to send a transaction to withdraw and obtain their funds.

This can simplify a smart contract that is sending funds to recipients, because the contract does not have to handle the cases of what to do if sending the funds fail.  A smart contract does not know whether sending the funds failed due to an actual error, or whether the recipient is a malicious smart contract that deliberately refuses to accept the funds.

Comment: How could a smart contract is able to refuse to accept the funds? @eth♦

Comment: @alper The classic example is a fallback function whose only code is `revert()`.